# How to find one value from a matrix

Tags: matlab

0I have on matrix-

```
A=[1 2 2 3 5 5;
   1 5 5 8 8 7;
   2 9 9 3 3 5];
```

From matrix i need to count now many nonzero elements ,how any 1,how many 2 and how many 3 in each row of given matrix"A".For these i have written one code like:

```
    [Ar Ac]=size(A);

    for j=1:Ar 
        for k=1:Ac
            count(:,j)=nnz(A(j,:));
            d(:,j)=sum(A(j,:)== 1); 
            e(:,j)=sum(A(j,:)==2);  
            f(:,j)=sum(A(j,:)==3);          
    end
end
```

but i need to write these using on loop i.e. here i manually use sum(A(j,:)== 1),sum(A(j,:)== 2) and sum(A(j,:)== 3) but is there any option where i can only write sum(A(j,:)== 1:3) and store all the values in the different row i.e, the result will be like-

```
b=[1 2 1;
   1 0 0;
   0 1 2];
```

Matlab experts need your valuable suggestions

Comment: is your output b correct? I don't think so

Comment: Sorry there was one mistake.Now it is edited.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple and general way. Just change `n` to however high you want to count. `n=max(A(:))` is probably a good general value.

```
 result = [];
   n = 3;
   for col= 1:n
       result = [result, sum(A==col, 2)];
   end
   result
```

e.g. for `n` = `10`

```
result =

   1   2   1   0   2   0   0   0   0   0
   1   0   0   0   2   0   1   2   0   0
   0   1   2   0   1   0   0   0   2   0
```

Comment: This uses a "for" loop :-/

Comment: @EitanT Agreed - your answer is better.

Comment: The issue with this is not the use of a `for` loop. `for` loops are perfectly fine. The issue is that the variable `result` is being dynamically allocated. If `n` is large and/or `A` has a lot of rows it could be an issue. But that could easily fixed.

Comment: @horchler This is of course debatable, but I think that relying on JIT is not good practice, especially if this is nested inside other, more complex loops. In most cases JIT does a pretty good job (especially in recent versions, though not always) but it's usually safer to make things easier for MATLAB an use built-in (vectorized and optimized) commands. I'd call it good practice rather than premature optimization...

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you're looking for a histogram count:

```
U = unique(A);
counts = histc(A', U)';
b = counts(:, ismember(U, [1 2 3]));
```

#### Example

```
%// Input matrix and vector of values to count
A = [1 2 2 3 5 5; 1 5 5 8 8 7; 2 9 9 3 3 5];
vals = [1 2 3];

%// Count values
U = unique(A);
counts = histc(A', U)';
b = counts(:, ismember(U, vals));
```

The result is:

```
b =
   1   2   1
   1   0   0
   0   1   2
```

Comment: Wouldn't this fail if the array includes 1.5? Or for array [1 3]?

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia I guess so. I've generalized it to be more robust. By the way, note that any of the solution proposed here fails for floating-point values unless it introduces a tolerance.

Answer (score 3):

Generalizing the sought values, as required by asker:

```
values = [ 1 2 3 ]; % or whichever values are sought
B = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@(x,y) sum(x==y,2), A, shiftdim(values,-1)),2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use this?

```
B=[];
for x=1:size(A,1)
B=[B;sum(A(x,:)==1),sum(A(x,:)==2),sum(A(x,:)==3)];
end
```

Comment: I want to write one generalized formula.In the given example i want to count from 1:3 but i also need to count from 1:4,1:5,1:10 in another code.That's why i don't want to write manually rather want to write 1:my given range.

Comment: @Luis Mendo provides a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this way:

```
B = [arrayfun(@(i) find(A(i,:) == 1) , 1:3 , 'UniformOutput', false)',arrayfun(@(i) find(A(i,:) == 2) , 1:3 , 'UniformOutput', false)',arrayfun(@(i) find(A(i,:) == 3) , 1:3 , 'UniformOutput', false)'];

res = cellfun(@numel, B);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a compact one:

```
sum(bsxfun(@eq, permute(A, [1 3 2]), 1:3),3)
```

You can replace `1:3` with any array.
you can make an anonymous function for it

```
rowcnt = @(M, R) sum(bsxfun(@eq, permute(M, [1 3 2]), R),3);
```

then running it on your data returns

```
>> rowcnt(A,1:3)

ans =

     1     2     1
     1     0     0
     0     1     2
```

and for more generalized case

```
>> rowcnt(A,[1 2 5 8])

ans =

     1     2     2     0
     1     0     2     2
     0     1     1     0
```

Comment: But the asker wants to generalize the "3"

Comment: @LuisMendo It is generalized. You can pass any array. I added another example to demonstrate it.

Comment: You're right. In fact, it's almost the same as my solution :-)